# Intercepting (Consuming) key events

Tags: flutter

I can successfully detect when the user has hit the `ENTER` key in a `TextField` by wrapping the `TextField` in a `RawKeyboardListener` and using the `onKey` function.  However, I want to prevent the `TextField` from receiving the `ENTER` keystroke and adding a new line.  How can I prevent the `ENTER` keystroke from being passed to the `TextField`?

Comment: do you want to stop user from adding new line or just enter key? cause user can copy, paste a text with multiple line

Comment: In this particular case, the user is pressing the ENTER key to select something, so I only want to prevent the enter keystroke from adding a new line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use focusNode:

```
final focusNode = FocusNode(onKey: (node, event) {
  if (event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.enter)) {
    return KeyEventResult.handled;
  }
  return KeyEventResult.ignored;
});
```

and then pass focusNode to your TextField

> The FocusManager receives key events from RawKeyboard and
> HardwareKeyboard and will pass them to the focused nodes. It starts
> with the node with the primary focus, and will call the onKey or
> onKeyEvent callback for that node. If the callback returns
> KeyEventResult.ignored, indicating that it did not handle the event,
> the FocusManager will move to the parent of that node and call its
> onKey or onKeyEvent. If that onKey or onKeyEvent returns
> KeyEventResult.handled, then it will stop propagating the event. If it
> reaches the root FocusScopeNode, FocusManager.rootScope, the event is
> discarded.

Comment: I don't understand how this prevents the enter key from being passed to the TextField.  Can you explain?